# iOS call to action tooltip component

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, tooltip

I am looking for a robust tooltip component written in Swift that would allow me to display instructions or "call to action" messages at certain moments. After researching I found several components but they either lack some of the functionalities I need or they don't seem so sturdy to me. The component should:

- Support device orientation changes
- Provide a delegate so I should know if the user dismissed the tooltip
- Be flexible and easy
  customizable
- Integration with Cocoapods would be a plus

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at [EasyTipView](https://github.com/teodorpatras/EasyTipView).

> EasyTipView is a custom tooltip view written in Swift that can be used
>   as a call to action or informative tip. It can be presented for any
>   UIBarButtonItem or UIView subclass. In addition it handles
>   automatically orientation changes and will always point to the correct
>   view or item.

To integrate EasyTipView into your Xcode project using `CocoaPods`, specify it in your Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'EasyTipView', '~> 0.1.0'
```

**Usage:**

1) First you should customize the preferences:

```
var preferences = EasyTipView.Preferences()
preferences.bubbleColor = UIColor(hue:0.58, saturation:0.1, brightness:1, alpha:1)
preferences.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
preferences.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Regular", size: 10)
preferences.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

2) Secondly you call the `showAnimated:forView:withinSuperview:text:preferences:delegate:` method:

```
EasyTipView.showAnimated(true, 
forView: self.buttonB, 
withinSuperview: self.navigationController?.view,
text: "Tip view inside the navigation controller's view. Tap to  dismiss!",
preferences: preferences,
delegate: self)
```

The `EasyTipViewDelegate` protocol defines one method to be called on the delegate after the EasyTipView has been dismissed.